# ASP.NET vNext CSS files issue

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, asp.net-core

I created a vNext project and uploaded to a Linux system. After a few hours it started working well, running "dnx kestrel" command I can reach the web page. However I experienced with an odd behaviour. After I start the application everything is ok - js, css and image files downloaded successfully. After the third-fourth refresh part of the css files are not available, the server responds with status 404, and after a few more refreshes none of them loaded anymore. The interesting thing is, that JS files and images are ok, so I think the wwwroot directory is fine.

In the Startup file I added the `app.UseStaticFiles()` line.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Ok, that's all I see:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://hu020029:5000/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css  
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[0]
      HttContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application.
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
      Request finished in 0,0001ms 404 
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://hu020029:5000/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css  
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware[0]
      HttContext.User merged via AutomaticAuthentication from authenticationScheme: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Application.
info: Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine[2]
      Request finished in 0,0001ms 404
```

Comment: Can you please try to collect more information? Your explanation doesn't have too many details. (1) Can you share the code? (2) Do you have any logs from the server, the static middleware should log stuff? (3) Is anything else other than static files still being served?

Comment: OK, I think it is a bug when we try to run an application directly from terminal (I use Suse linux), however when I start from a Docker image, everything is fine.